# c++ GMock SetArgReferee as CStringArray

Tags: c++, mfc, googletest, googlemock

Using c++11 with MFC, and trying to create some unit tests with gtest 1.7, I've encountered a problem. I want to mock a nasty method without changing the declaration or the definition of the method below.

```cpp
virtual bool  getValue(CStringArray& valueOut) const;
```

Mocking is simple, `MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(getValue,bool(CStringArray&));` will do this for me. However, using in the test case, I cannot make it work.
The relevant part from the test case:

```cpp
CStringArray localArray;
localArray.Add("Only One Element");
EXPECT_CALL(object, getValue(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgReferee<0>(localArray), Return(true)));
```

This gives me a compilation error, because `CStringArray` (as derived from `CObject`) is not-copyable, not-movable object. My question is,
**How can I alter the return array using only mock functions?**

I know that I can create a hybrid mock, with a real function building up the array, but it would be harder for me to add custom elements to each test case. Something like:

```
struct MockNastyObject : public NastyObject {
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(getValueMock, bool(CStringArray&));
    virtual bool getValue(CStringArray& arr) const override{
        arr.Add("Element1");
        getValueMock(arr);
    }
};
```

This approach could work, as I can set expectation for the `getValueMock` and alter the array with the non-mock method.

Comment: I have this `getValue` function, that uses the database - what I can't and don't want in a test. It returns the value in the parameter I provide, in this case a `CStringArray`. Ohh, and returns `true` if it succeed.  So, I'd like to fill that array with different fake values in each test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create a [gmock action](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/actions.html) as seen below.

First, you need to create a helper method, that will populate your array when setting the expectation (out of class or test case as mentioned in the documentation). Then set a proper `EXPECT_CALL` to make it work.

```cpp
struct MockNastyObject : public NastyObject {
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(getValue, bool(CStringArray&));
};

ACTION_P(AddParamToCArray, param) { arg0.Add(param); }

TEST(testOne, populateTest)
{
    MockNastyObject myMock;
    EXPECT_CALL(myMock, getValue(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(
        WithArg<0>(AddParamToCArray("First element")),
        WithArg<0>(AddParamToCArray("Second element")),
        Return(true)));
    ...
}
```

As you can see, this can be useful not only to `CStringArray` but any container, that supports `Add`.
The initial question was about `SetArgReferee` although the solution does not use it.

Also, [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66981921/14583599) could be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you want to achieve - the fist code snippet is the assignment, the second code snippet is the element addition. As for the second one, it can be done with a lambda w/o a custom specialized action:

```
CStringArray localArray;
localArray.Add("Only One Element");
EXPECT_CALL(object, getValue(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(
  WithArg<0>([&localArray](CStringArray& a) { a.Add(localArray[0]); }),
  Return(true)));
```

Or simplified w/o the `localArray`:

```
EXPECT_CALL(object, getValue(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(
  WithArg<0>([](CStringArray& a) { a.Add("Only One Element"); }),
  Return(true)));
```